# Simple Groovy WS client is failing but why?

Tags: soap, groovy, groovyws

i am trying to use Groovy WS and use the following code.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules', module='groovyws', version='0.5.2')
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient

proxy = new WSClient("http://lyricwiki.org/server.php?wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()

result = proxy.searchArtist("shakira")
println "${result}"
```

It should be simple, but somehow it fails with a failure telling me:

> Caught:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException:
>   Failed to create service.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatly, if GroovyWS is awesome when deployed against a well-known web-service, discovering web-services abilities with it may sometimes be ... difficult, as all and everything is hidden below the proxy.

Poersonnally, when trying to connect to a WSDL web-service, my first weapon is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

I first try to connect to WS using SoapUI, then perform all the requests I will latter try to execute in groovy-world. This way, I get errors more readable than with GroovyWS (although I really like its simplicity).

Comment: When using SoapUI the service is nicely resolved and i can execute methods on the service without problems. Any clue what to do next ?

Comment: I tried the webservice using Apache CXF and the wsdl2java fails, so it seemed that the webservice wsdl was not correct or something. I tried another webservice one (http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?WSDL) and that worked perfect.